# Word for requiring a lot of input

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

According to Google, verbose means:

> using or expressed in more words than are needed.

From that definition, I understand that verbose generally means "producing a lot of output." The word I'm looking for is something that more closely fits "requiring a lot of input."

Using programming languages, I could say that "Java is a very verbose programming language," intending to mean that Java requires a lot more programming than, say, Python to perform the same operation. However, saying that Java is very verbose is really saying that Java tends to produce a lot of output, not require a lot of input.

Is there a word that describes this definition

> requiring more input/feedback than is thought to be necessary (esp. in comparison to something else)

that would fit in the following sentence

> While Python allows a programmer to write short, concise programs, Java is very ____.

Comment: See [Software Engineering.SE: How to determine if a programming language is verbose or terse?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50150/how-to-determine-if-a-programming-language-is-verbose-or-terse).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "*the inverse (not opposite)*". Certainly a language can be *verbose*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm, funnily enough, not sure of the word I need to use there. I'm looking for a word that means "requiring lots of input," instead of what verbose means: "producing lots of output." Sorry about it being unclear.

Comment: IMHO, you are misinterpreting this. A programming language that is verbose requires the programmer to produce a lot of code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k but that's not what I'm asking, nor how verbose is being used. This is in the context of Debian vs. Arch, but it's the same meaning http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33198300#33198300

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've rewritten the question. Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: @Mick that doesn't really answer my question unfortunately. I was using the wrong description for what I wanted. I don't care about output, but rather about input.

Comment: I still don't understand your terminology. A programming language has no input nor output. Unless you count business rules as the input and the program that implements them as the output. In any case, it is customary to call a language *verbose* if it requires the programmer to write code that is longer than comparable code in other languages.

Comment: @michael.hor257k output as in console output, like for a command line app. Input as in what you actually have to type to create a program.

Comment: When we say that a programming language is verbose, what we're actually saying is that programs written in the language are verbose. It's pretty common to describe a language in terms of the qualities of its programs. We do the same thing with human languages: a language can be described as "sonorous" if speaking it is generally sonorous.

Comment: @Barmar OK, maybe I should use a better example then.

Comment: Using your definition **requiring more input/feedback than is thought to be necessary (esp. in comparison to something else)** are you looking for _data-hungry_? I don't believe that this is a good description of a verbose programming language but could be a good description of an analytical program or even a modelling process which has not been automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *input* is not usually used to describe the act of programming, but rather the input required when a program runs.  The term *data-hungry* is usually used to denote a program that requires a lot of data input.

One could adapt this terminology to describe the act of writing a program as being *code-hungry*, however this is not a standard term.  Having said that, I do believe that any programmer reading the sentence :

> While Python allows a programmer to write short, concise programs, Java is very code-hungry.

will know exactly what is meant.

---

TL/DR;

The main reason a programming language like Python requires less code than Java is that Python includes built-in data typing.  In Python, even high level data types like *lists*, *sets*, *tuples*, and even *arrays* require no explicit declaration of type.

Here I have used a standard term - namely *higher level*.  Python is a *higher level* programming language than Java.

Comment: I definitely like this answer. It fits with what I was thinking. Since this has been bumped, I do want to see if someone has a better match, but otherwise, I think this works well. If I forget to accept, remind me; I do too many things at once :p.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks.  Ya - I thought it was an interesting question to think about - even with my amateur programming experience.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "verbose" accurately describes both "using or expressed in," i.e., the experiences of writer and user. Thus, "...Java requires verbosity." will work fine here, or you can use "verbose" in the original sentence because it is clear that you are writing about the programmer's (writer's) perspective.

Comment: The problem is that my question isn't actually about that specific instance. It's just an example. And Java requiring verbosity is different from Java being verbose. I guess a word that means "something requiring verbosity" would fit.